# How to measure quantization noise?

Tags: digital-logic

I was experimenting with software (National Instruments Signal Express) where I used a 16 bit A/D converter, I connected the analogue input to ground at a range of -10V to +10V

I've calculated the theoretical rms quantization noise to be:

$$88.0μV$$

I have exported the data from the graph below to an excel sheet, where I have time values and voltage values...how do I go about obtaining the measured rms quantization noise?

[image]

EDIT:

I tried using the SNR formula and rearranging in terms of rms quantization, and managed to get a value close to it, would this be correct?

These are the readings:

[image]

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283423/2451

Comment: I have deleted the question on Physics exchange.

Comment: What about using the definition of rms? \$x_{\mathrm{rms}} =
\sqrt{ \frac{1}{n} \left( x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 \right) }\$

Comment: I think it is relevant to understand why you care about making the measurement. Ultimately, there are many different sources of noise - depending what is important you might for example want to measure bit-error-rate, and work back from there.

Comment: @VladimirCravero I tried using that but how do I calculate the error? using the readings I have before finding the rms

Comment: Why do you want the rms quantization noise? What are you planning to do with that number?  Most of the time, the quantization step size is a more useful figure, and you can just read that off your graph as 160uV.  The actual rms quantization noise is signal dependant, and not trivial to measure unless it is the only noise present.

Comment: @JackB I was set task to calculate the rms quantization noise, which I did for -10V to +10V range, then I was asked to measure this experimentally by taking Analogue input of the A/C and ground it and acquiring 1000 samples, that's what I have above in the graph, apparently there is a way to measure the rms quantization noise using the data I have above displayed in the excel sheet, is there a way? I've been going around in circles since 4pm yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- With a 16 bit ADC and if exactly 20V range (+/-10) and 65535 steps,
- each quantum step should be 305.1804 uV,

  - you show 325 uV steps in excel. and about 150uV steps in the graph. why?
- With 0V input , you appear to have a mean offset (-519 uV)
- Quantization Noise is the addition of Quantization errors to an input analog noise.
- rms noise is the same as "standard deviation" or sigma, s

I prefer to compute 3sigma because it is a useful metric for Test Process Capability levels or Cpk to extend the random sample to 99.7% of the population. This can be compared with upper & lower control limits to determine the ratio of margin or to see if a product is "good enough" to give high yields or consistent results by the Cpk ratio (>>1). 
If Cpk <1, you have a big problem.

I wouldn't waste much time on RMS noise unless you want to compute SNR after offset and gain errors are verified and corrected.

- Actually the dithering of quantum levels can be used to get greater resolution by averaging and only with random noise get a reduction of standard deviation by n^0.5 for n measurements. This averaging is effectively a reduction of quantization bandwidth.

Comment: I did as followed and received a value of 217uV, theoretical is 88.09uV, could there be contributions to the error? I'll have a look at 3sigma, now that you mention it, we were only learning about it last week

Comment: Re-examine your 0V input and ensure it is the  shortest path and not an inductive loop prone to external noise pickup.  The ideal case and that there is no common mode noise perhaps with ground currents or ground voltage noise. We have no idea what you are measuring is external or internal noise.

Comment: Thinking about it now, there was 2 wires, one from the ground, and one from the input...we joined them together by hand, is it possible it could have picked up external noise from that?

Comment: apologies for all the questions, I'd be happy with 217uV knowing that it was our mess up in the lab that caused the error

Comment: most likely external noise.. How did you compute V in excel considering the step size is different?

Comment: What do you mean by compute V? the standard deviation? or the voltage values I received in excel? the stepsize is almost the same as the theoretical value? the graph may look like 150uV, but the data says otherwise if you look at the stepsize between them

Comment: If your stated assumptions are correct the step size is 305uV yet the graph is clearly ~150 implying 10V range or 16 bits plus sign bit and insufficient data in excel but shows 325uV.   There seems to a couple errors here.

Comment: My understanding of this is that the quantization error is the difference between the actual value and the digitized value, since it was 0V, shouldn't the error be the values received in excel? -519uV, -194uV wouldn't they be the errors? the difference from ground? so shouldn't it be easy as squaring these values, finding the average then the square root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46225/discussion-between-tony-stewart-ee-since-75-and-modrisco).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, quantization noise does not exist.

When you quantize a signal in amplitude you commit a **quantization error** because your ADC has a finite number of levels. If you are quantizing a voltage signal then we can call the amplitude of a level of your ADC \$\Delta v\$. E.g., if your ADC has an input range from \$-1\$ V to \$+1\$ V and is a 10 bit converter, then the total number of levels is \$2^{10}=1024\$ and \$\Delta v = \frac{+1\ \mathrm{V} - (-1\ \mathrm{V})}{1024}=19.53\ \mathrm{mV}\$.

If your current sample is at \$0.6\ \mathrm{V}\$ and you have a perfect ADC, its output would be code 819, which corresponds to an input voltage of \$599.61\ \mathrm{mV}\$. You are committing an absolute error of \$390\ \mu\mathrm{V}\$, and this is **quantization error**.

Since engineers are good at working with [AWGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise), i.e. Additive White Gaussian Noise, they try to model this error, which is a stochastic process, as if it was AWGN.

If your input signal respects some [hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(signal_processing)#The_additive_noise_model_for_quantization_error) then this model is sort of valid and the power of this quantization noise can be calculated as:
$$
P_n = \frac{\Delta v^2}{12}\ [\mathrm{V^2}]
$$
This is a fundamental formula when speaking of quantization noise, try to remember it.

In your case \$\Delta v = 305\ \mu\mathrm{V}\$, thus \$P_n=7.76\ \mathrm{nV^2}\$. If you take the square root you get \$\sqrt{P_n}=88.1\ \mu\mathrm{V}\$, so far so good.

What you are trying to do is to feed a certain signal to your ADC, compute the ADC output, calculate the quantization error and finally calculate the rms value of the error, to see if it approaches the ideal minimum value of 
\$\frac{\Delta v^2}{12}\$.

Now we have to differentiate: it is clear that your system is "amplitude quantized", but is it also time quantized? This is very important because the formula to calculate the rms value of a sequence is different from the formula that works for a continuous function.

Anyway, if you feed your ADC with a continuous time signal \$x(t)\$ your output will either be \$y(t)\$ or \$y_n\$, depending if your system also samples or not.

The error can be calculated as the difference between the input and the output:
$$
\epsilon(t) = x(t) - y(t)\\
\epsilon_n = x(nT) - y_n
$$
where T is the sampling period, if present.

Finally, for a continuous function:
$$
\epsilon_{\mathrm{rms}} = \sqrt {{1 \over {T_2-T_1}} {\int_{T_1}^{T_2} {[\epsilon(t)]}^2\, dt}}
$$
where \$T_1\$ and \$T_2\$ are the starting and ending of the interval in which you want to calculate the rms.

For a sequence:
$$
\epsilon_{\mathrm{rms}} =
\sqrt{ \frac{1}{N} \left( \sum_i \epsilon_i^2 \right) }
$$
where N is the total number of samples and the sum is intended to be over all the samples.

Please note that in a real system you do not get only quantization noise. There are many other sources of noise that will be present in your ADC readings, ranging from electrical noise to nonlinearities of the ADC. Quantization noise is something specifically meant to characterize only one aspect of ADCs and does not take in account other noise sources in the ADC, nor the rest of the conversion chain.

The \$P_n\$ calculated early on is just a "you can't do better than this" value, so expect to get greater numbers from a real system. Due to the fact that the hypothesis for the formula to be valid are rarely completely respected, even an ideal system will have a greater noise power for many "nice" input signals.

Comment: +1. You say quantization noise does not exist but then go ahead to use the term in your second-to-last paragraph. Is that a mistake?

Comment: No. I use the term after stressing the fact that it is a model we build, and that it requires some hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the rms noise from a sequence of measurements taken of a DC reading, do this.

Find the average value. Subtract it from all the readings to get the 'errors'. Square the errors. Take the average of the squared errors (or sum them and divide by the number of them, same thing). Take the square root of their average. That's the Root(Mean(Squared_Errors)), or RMS error.

Comment: Why are you calling the samples at +130uV and -1167 uV "+/-4 steps"? If you are calling -520 uV the "mean", then -194 uV and -843 uV are +/-1 step, and +130 uV and -1167 uV are +/-2 steps. No "missing codes" in this sample. In any case, this answer is about the *total* RMS noise, and has nothing to do with quantization noise specifically.

Comment: @DaveTweed AH! so those 'samples' at -360 and -680 are not samples, but a kink halfway along the line! Doh! Right, so the step size is 320u. Edited.

Comment: @Neil_UK, I did as advised, and manged to get 217u...which is out by alot..probably the best I'll get at this stage

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can determine from the data you show is the quantization step size, which is 324 µV. Clearly, at this particular input voltage, the quantization step is larger than the theoretical value of 20V/2<sup>16</sup> = 305 µV.

If a signal is (or can be approximated by) a linear ramp, then the quantization error signal is a sawtooth waveform that has a peak-to-peak amplitude equal to the quantization step size. This sawtooth is the difference between the original signal and a reconstructed signal produced by an "ideal DAC" with no filtering — i.e., one that holds each sample value at its output until the next one comes along.

The RMS value of a sawtooth is \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\$ the peak-to-peak value, so the quantization error amplitude generated by this ADC could be expressed as \$\frac{324}{\sqrt{12}} = 93.5 \mu V_{RMS}\$.

However, this is not how signals are used in practice. DACs are followed by reconstruction filters, so we normally treat the quantization noise as a separate sequence of random samples that have a uniform distribution over a span equal to the quantization step size. These random samples represent the difference between the value produced by your ADC and the one produced by an "ideal" ADC with infinite precision. For simplicity, we assume that this noise is "white" in terms of its frequency distribution, but in fact, the spectrum of the noise is very dependent on the signal being digitized.

The RMS value of a sequence of random samples with uniform distribution over the range ±half the quantization step size is, once again, \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\$ the step size. In other words, either way you look at it, the RMS value of the quantization error comes out the same.